# Why am I getting two different IP addresses?

Tags: router, internet, ip, isp, google-search

I have a dynamic PPPoE connection from my ISP. After logging in, the router says it's connected through 172.80.xx.xx (this is not the DHCP range for connected users), but in Google, when I search for "what is my ip", it shows 202.124.xx.xx. Why is this?

Comment: We probably need a bit more information to help you.  Run a traceroute to see if that shows anything of interest.  Also make sure you don't have a VPN connection running as that would cause you to see two different IPs. You can also do a reverse IP lookup on both IPs and that might shed some slight

Answer (score 2):

Your ISP is most likely doing NAT (network address translation), most likely to make up for a shortage of publicly routable IPv4 addresses. When an ISP does NAT, we call it "Carrier-Grade NAT" (CGNAT).

It's weird that the "private" address you're getting is 172.**80**.x.x, as that's not an RFC 1918 private address. It would make more sense if it were 172.16.x.x - 172.31.x.x.